# How to get non mocked locations like Google Maps does?

Tags: android, android-location

When I enable Mock locations in the developer options and install Programs like [CatchMeIfUCan](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kr.woot0pia.gps) Almost all applications accept the mocked location. Except Google Maps. Google Maps always shows my real location.

How does Google Maps do this? Is there a special API to get the correct location?

Comment: maybe  Location.getProvider  will give you clues

Answer (score 0):

If your app uses FusedLocationProviderApi then you can check if the location you get is mocked/real by checking [KEY_MOCK_LOCATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#KEY_MOCK_LOCATION).